# Different templates for different entry types within a section

Tags: templating, entry-type

When specifying the URL and template used to render a section, it's possible to set variable URLs using something like `/{postDate.year}/{slug}`. Is there any way to accomplish something similar for the entry template, or do all the differences have to be handled within one template that checks for entry type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this: https://craftcms.com/support/entry-type-templates

Comment: I think he wants to know if he can do it *without* doing that; by using something like `something/{type}/{slug}` for the URI and `something/{type}` for the Entry Template

Comment: Won't be the last time I've been wrong!

Comment: @khalwat was right about what I was asking, but I didn't even stop to think about using variable includes instead, which should work just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to have dynamic tags within Entry Template settings, no. All fields that do allow dynamic tags will say so in their instruction text.

The reason it’s allowed in some settings but not others is because there is a performance hit each time those dynamic settings are rendered. (We actually spin up Twig to do the parsing, but since the settings are not stored as actual files, Twig must re-recompile the settings every single time.) So we only do it in areas where the performance hit doesn’t matter much. Entry URL Format settings, for example, only have to get parsed when an entry is saved, not each time that the entry is actually requested on the front end.